# Firebase: User shall only see, what he added to firebase. No one else should see the data of another user. How?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, backend

The question is formulated pretty much suming up my problem. I somehow cannot figure out, how to achieve this. I guess I would have to add some lines of code to the cloud firestore?

What would you do?

At the moment I have a working auth system and a user can add new data and retrieve existing data from the firebase.
But to point out my issue again: They should only be allowed, to see their own data and post data, which only they can see.

I really hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up the Security Rules in your database and their corresponding conditions. The [Official Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions) has some pretty well written and useful information on how to accomplish exactly just that, which you should find very useful. For your particular use case, an example straight from the documentation

> If you wanted to restrict access to this data such that only the
> logged-in user can see their own data, your rules would look something
> like this.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```